# Toggle button for collapsible log in form will not stay fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I'm working with CSS grids and while doing so had the idea to make a collapsible login/registration form, using a jQuery toggle method. I got close to reaching the desired output, minus the fact that the actual "Close / Open" toggle link moves to the center of the parent div when the toggle is open, and slides to the far right once it's closed. How do I prevent this from happening? I am including the published link to my project as well as the code

Here is my jQuery, 
and the HTML (in which the jQuery actually lies)
Finally, this is the CSS to match

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

                            // Expand Panel
                            $("#open").click(function(){
                                $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");   
                            });

                            // Collapse Panel
                            $("#close").click(function(){
                                $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
                            }); 

                            // Switch buttons from "Log In | Register" to "Close Panel" on click
                            $("#toggle a").click(function () {
                                $("#toggle a").toggle();
                            });
                        });
```

```css
/* CSS3 GRIDS */
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
#wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;  /* set grid to 3 columns */
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    grid-gap: 1em;
    justify-items: stretch; /* start, end, center, stretch(default) */
    align-items: stretch;/* start, end, center, stretch(default) */

    }


#wrapper > div {
    background: white;
    padding: 1em;

    }   

/* #wrapper > div:nth-child(odd){
    background: #ddd;
    }
*/
#logo {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Solway', serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #111111;
}

#nav-links {
    list-style-type: none;  
}

#nav-links > li {
    display: inline-block;

    padding: 0px 40px;
}

#nav-links > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;

}

#nav-links > li > a:hover {
    color: green;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #40c249;
    font-style: italic;
}

#sign-in {
    float:right;
}

#nav {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* sliding panel */
#toggle {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.tab {

}

.clearfix {
    /* display: none; */
}


.tog {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #40c249;
}
#toppanel {
    position: relative;   /*Panel will overlap  content */
    /*position: relative;*/   /*Panel will "push" the content down */
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.box {
    border-radius: 5px;
}   

.header {
    /* align-self: start; */
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row:1/3;
}

.content {
    /* align-self: end; */
    grid-row: 3/7; 
    grid-column: 1/3;
}

.aside {
    /* justify-self: end; */    
    grid-column: 3/4;  
    grid-row: 3/5;


}

.aside2 {
    /*grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2/4;  ovlaps box 1 - eliminates margin negative*/
    grid-row: 5/7;
    grid-column: 3/4;
}   

.article {
    grid-row: 7;
    grid-column: 1/2;
}   

.article2 {
    grid-row:7;
    grid-column:2/4;
}   

.footer {
 grid-column: 1/4;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box header">
                <div id="logo">Web D & D</div>
                <div id="sign-in">
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function() {

                            // Expand Panel
                            $("#open").click(function(){
                                $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");   
                            });

                            // Collapse Panel
                            $("#close").click(function(){
                                $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
                            }); 

                            // Switch buttons from "Log In | Register" to "Close Panel" on click
                            $("#toggle a").click(function () {
                                $("#toggle a").toggle();
                            });
                        });
                    </script>

                    <!-- The tab on top --> 
                    <div class="tab">
                        <ul class="login">
                            <li id="toggle">
                                <a id="open" class="open tog" style="display: none;" href="#?signin">Log In | Register</a>
                                <a id="close" class="close tog" href="#">Close Panel</a>         
                            </li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div> <!-- / top --><br><br>
                <!-- Panel -->
                <div id="toppanel">
                    <div id="panel">
                        <div class="content clearfix">
                            <div class="left">
                                <!-- Login Form -->
                                <form class="clearfix" action="#" method="post">
                                    <h1>Sign In</h1>
                                    <label class="grey" for="log">Username:</label>
                                    <input class="field" type="text" name="log" id="log" value="" size="23" />
                                    <label class="grey" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                    <input class="field" type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="23" />
                                    <label><input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
                                    <a class="lost-pwd" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="left right">            
                                <!-- Register Form -->
                                <form action="#" method="post">
                                    <h1>Not a member yet? Sign Up!</h1>             
                                    <label class="grey" for="signup">Username:</label>
                                    <input class="field" type="text" name="signup" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                                    <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label>
                                    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="23" />
                                    <label>A password will be e-mailed to you.</label>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="bt_register" />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- /login -->  


    </div> <!--panel -->
                </div><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                <div id="nav">
                    <ul id="nav-links">
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="box content">Content</div>

            <div class="box aside">Aside</div>

            <div class="box aside2">Aside2</div>

            <div class="box article">Article</div>

            <div class="box article2">Article2</div>

            <div class="box footer">Footer</div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://www.yadahandthehunter.com/grids/grid-5.html

Thanks! Hope someone sees this soon! ;)

-MAJ

Answer (score 1):

CSS can easily fix this:

```
.open, .close {
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Yes @WebMarie is currect .But should put top:20px or qaccording to your position